# How to transfer only useful data from CouchDB to PouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to replicate only last revision from couchDB to pouchDB, but it's transfer doc with all revs. Initial example:

```
var replicationOptions = {
    doc_ids: null
};

this.$get = function (pouchDB, arrayUtils, $rootScope, modelUtils,appConfig) {

    function initDB() {
        userLocalDB = pouchDB("mobile_users", {
            revs_limit: 1,
            auto_compaction: true,
            adapter: 'cordova-sqlite',
            iosDatabaseLocation: 'Library',
            androidDatabaseImplementation: 2
        });
        userRemoteDB = pouchDB(appConfig.couchDBServerUrl+"mobile_users", {skipSetup: true});
        userRemoteDB.login("mobile", "fakepass");
    }...
```

Replication code:

```
function startReplication(username) {
        replicationOptions.doc_ids = [_prefixId + username];
        console.log("replicationOptions", replicationOptions)

        return userRemoteDB.replicate.to(userLocalDB, replicationOptions).$promise
            .then(null, null, function (progress) {
                console.log('user replication status', progress);
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log('user replication resolved with', result);
                return true
            })
            .catch(function (reason) {
                console.log('user replication exception', reason);
                return startReplication(username);
            })
    }
```

Result of progress in console.log('user replication status', progress);

```
user replication status Object {change: Object}
change: Object
doc_write_failures: 0
docs: Array(604)
docs_read: 604
docs_written: 604
errors: Array(0)
last_seq: 452349
ok: true
start_time: "2017-07-07T18:37:34.353Z"
```

I'm looking for answer for long time, but any solutions was effective. I don't want transfer from couchDB 604 revs of just 1 doc of 25Kb. Think about 25 kb x 603 of useless data tranferred over a 2g/3g connection and help me to tranfer only useful data.

OBS: Fauxton Compact & Clean was used before this process

Comment: Do you make changes in PouchDB that get synced to CouchDB?  Or do all changes originate in CouchDB, and PouchDB's copy is read-only?

Comment: Both sides has changes, most of the changes comes from CouchDB

Comment: In that case, the extra revs aren't useless data; they're used for conflict resolution.

Comment: Suppose that my cellphone is with no local data, and is first replication, there's no conflict to resolve, I just want last revision replicated to my local

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [pouchdb-load](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-load) to

> Load documents into CouchDB/PouchDB from a dumpfile

Then, sync as usual and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I'll test it

Comment: Unfortunantely, it's a workaround, because I don't desire load dump file, but load couchDB doc. To achieve this with pouchdb-load, I need to load a file out of this structure (CouchDB/PouchDB) to after include it.